# Changing tab order doesn't give user option to save

Tags: bug, user-interface, new-nav

If I re-order my tabs, but don't edit them in any other way, the "Save" button does not become active so I can't save my changes. It's not auto-saving the tab order: when I refresh the page, the order resets.

If I reorder the tabs and make some other change to one of them, like renaming one, the "Save" button becomes active and when I save the order is saved as well.

I got the following results when I run `localStorage.getItem("newNav")` in the browser console, as requested by Sklivvz♦. All browsers are running on Windows 7 and the results were the same when running the script before and after moving the custom new-tav tab over to the left 2 tabs over:

**Google Chrome (6.0.2490.80 m)**

> {"questionLists":[{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/votes"},{"name":null,"uri":"/‌​questions/active"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/tagged/css"}]}

**Firefox (41.0.2)**

> [Exception... "Component is not available" nsresult: "0x80040111
>   (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code ::
>    :: line 1" data: no]

**IE (10)** (this test was on Meta)

> {"questionLists":[{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/votes"},{"name":null,"uri":"/‌​questions/active"},{"uri":"/questions/tagged/new-nav"}]}

Comment: it should be autosaving the tab order

Comment: @Sklivvz - Does it take a bit to do so? Could the problem be that I'm just leaving the page too soon?

Comment: It should be instant, can you tell me the order you can't save and the result of running `localStorage.getItem("newNav")` in your browser console?

Comment: Before and after I moved a tab named 'css' I got: `"{"questionLists":[{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/votes"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/active"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/tagged/css"}]}"` This is in Google Chrome version Version 46.0.2490.80 m on Windows 7.

Comment: I hadn't even noticed this issue until I saw this post. Nice catch.

Comment: This also occurs in Firefox (41.0.2) but trying to run the code to check localStorage gives me an error: `[Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]`

Comment: @Sklivvz - IE behaves the same way as Chrome. I tested it on Meta as well, same issue: `"{"questionLists":[{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/votes"},{"name":null,"uri":"/questions/active"},{"uri":"/questions/tagged/new-nav"}]}" ` before and after moving the `new-tav` tab over to the left 2 tabs over.